# Golang: meaning of the code (write interface inside bracket)

Tags: go

```
func Unwrap(err error) error {
    // what is the meaning of this code
    u, ok := err.(interface {
            Unwrap() error
    })
    if !ok {
            return nil
    }
    return u.Unwrap()
}
```

This is the source code from errors pkg.
I am wondering what is the usage of

```
err.(interface {})
```

Comment: `v.(T)` is a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions). The expression in the example asserts that `err` is of a type that implements the anonymous `interface { Unwrap() error }` interface type. The result of a type assertion is a value of the asserted type and a boolean informing you whether or not the assertion was correct.

Comment: Thanks! I know the usage of v.(T). Because such usage is rare so I cannot recognise it immediately. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```golang
u, ok := err.(interface {
            Unwrap() error
    })
```

This code ensures that err object(it is an interface indeed) has a method with signature `Unwrap() error`. Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)
type myError struct{}
func (e myError) Error() string {
    return "it is my error"
}
func main() {
    var e1 error
    e1 = &myError{}
    u, ok := e1.(interface {
            Unwrap() error
    })
    fmt.Printf("e1: %v -> %v\n",u,ok)
    e2 := fmt.Errorf("E2: %w", e1)

    u, ok = e2.(interface {
            Unwrap() error
    })
    fmt.Printf("e2: %v -> %v\n",u,ok)
}
```

This will print

```sh
e1: <nil> -> false
e2: E2: it is my error -> true
```

Go playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/nw3H13u2Bbs).

Answer (score 0):

The error type is an interface type. An error variable represents any value that can describe itself as a string. Here is the interface's declaration:

```
type error interface {
    Error() string
}
```

For more details refer - https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go